# Ansible playbook to create output to logfile

Tags: linux, unix, ansible

This is one little part of my working ansible playbook. 
I want to send the information which will be gathered to a log file (which the playbook will create)
I have tried so many different way but getting no where.

No error is coming back which can only tell me that the script is working but I guess its going somewhere else other than the destination which I would like it to do

Here is my script

Would be grateful of your thoughts and help

```
 - name: netstat check 
   shell: netstat -tulnp | awk '{print $4}' | sed -n 's/.*:\([^",]*\)[",]*$/\1/p'
   register: netstat

 - name: copy output to local file
   copy:
    content: "{{ netstat.stdout}}"
    dest: "/home/user_name/netstat.txt"
```

Thanks

Comment: Please use code snippet for your code.

Comment: What is the content of `/home/user_name/netstat.txt` on the target host after your playbook has run ? How does it differ from `netstat.stdout` (it should not...) ? What were you expecting exactly ? Please add those information to your question by editing it and take time to format it correctl as explained by @RickardKörkkö

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Within the host I was expecting it to create a file within my own directory and folder. I have been looking and a variety of examples and they were separating them like this that's all. Thank you for your help and thoughts

Comment: This should have created a (literallly) `/home/user_name/netstat.txt` file on your target host with the content. Did you check that?

Comment: Hi Zeirounator... cheers for you reply. Yes it is there but I would like it on the server that im currently on. To save jumping onto that. Obv the playbook is pointing to a different server than the one that im on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed your playbook in my ansible server(hosts: localhost) and it works fine. A new file is created with the required output.

Incase you want it on the localhost, try giving delegate_to: localhost

```
- name: copy output to local file
  copy:
    content: "{{ netstat.stdout}}"
    dest: "/home/user_name/netstat.txt"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: You nailed it. Yes the "delegate_to" was needed. Thank you so much for your help! A learning curve but having fun doing it. Thanks once again Kev